# Change the text direction from left to right of a post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, edit, google-web-designer

I am an editor on the WordPress website and when I published a post in Arabic, and I want to change the direction of the Title in a  post from left to the right how can I do that in WordPress!

Answer (score 1):

Open the header.php file and Replace it with the below code

`<body <? php body_class(); ?>>` with: `<body <? php body_class(); ?> dir="ltr">`

Save the file and clear the cache and cookie and try. but make sure here this `dir="ltr"` only needs to add when you open the blog page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Step 1 –
   Ensure your WordPress theme has RTL support
   go to /wp-content/themes/yourtheme and look for a file called rtl.css. I
2. Step 2 –
   Test RTL support
   Go to Plugins -> Add New and search for “RTL Tester”
   after instal it:
   Once you click “Switch to RTL” the WordPress user interface switches to RTL mode.
3. Step 3 –
   Enable RTL Support permanently
   Open up your wp-config.php and add the following:

   define ('WPLANG', 'ar');

Then hop on over to Settings -> General -> Site Language – and select your language.

read more:[How to enable Right-to-left (RTL) support in WordPress](https://createandcode.com/how-to-enable-right-to-left-rtl-support-in-wordpress/)